# Spring Data JPA check if object exits where elementcollecion is equal to list

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have created element collection that contains ids to another table

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "participantchatchannel", joinColumns = 
@JoinColumn(name = "channelId"))
@Column(name = "participantId")
private List<Long> participantsIdList;
```

I can see that the list contains the values I want it to contain. Now I want to check if there is an object that contains exactly the same Ids I am providing.

I have tried expanding CrudRepository like so:

```
boolean existsByParticipantsIdListEquals(List<Long> participantIdList);
```

But I keep getting error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

What am I doing wrong and why (possibly I don't quite understand what sql is generated by this).

Edit:

After enabling logs I can see following lines in console:

```
2018-08-10 07:27:14.997 DEBUG 8880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select TOP(?) chatchanne0_.id as col_0_0_ from chatchannel chatchanne0_ left outer join participantchatchannel participan1_ on chatchanne0_.id=participan1_.channel_id where participan1_.participant_id=(? , ?)
2018-08-10 07:27:15.001 TRACE 8880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [2]
2018-08-10 07:27:15.002 TRACE 8880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [3]
2018-08-10 07:27:15.005  WARN 8880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
2018-08-10 07:27:15.005 ERROR 8880 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: can you please post the SQL statement that causes the error?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have updated question with stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is wrong. You cannot use Equals with a collection as argument. 
That's why Hibernate generate an invalid where clause:

```
where participan1_.participant_id=(? , ?)
```

You have to use In. So your query should look like:

```
boolean existsByParticipantsIdListIn(List<Long> participantIdList);
```

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't quite work. I have [2,3] and [2,4] and returns true for both.

Comment: can you please post the SQL that Hibernate generates?